# Get longitude and latitude in java

Tags: java, linux, geolocation, ip-address

I want track my location using longitude and latitude in linux

I am trying get longitude and latitude using public ip address but i want using system ip address

Comment: What do you mean "system ip address"? You mean the address of your computer on your own network?

Comment: yes i want access my longitude and latitude of my system

Answer (score 1):

There is no link between your system's ip address and a location. imagine your system's IP address being 192.168.0.1.

Also: The coordinates your your public IP address are probably the ones of your ISPs datacenter, not of your device.

What are your actually trying to achieve?

Comment: my only motto access my system longitude and latitude using java . can you help me?

Comment: Unless your system has a GPS tracking device attached and that device has an API that can be accessed using Java - you can't. By default neither Windows nor Linux Systems have coordinates, best they do it guess the location from the system's public IP.